# Select every value (even when it is null) with inner join sql

Tags: sql, select

This is my sql select statment

```
SELECT k.name, c.name AS nameCustomer, o.*
                                        FROM offertes o
                                        INNER JOIN customers k
                                        ON o.idCustomer= k.id
                                        INNER JOIN contactperson c
                                        ON o.idContact = c.id;
```

When `o.idContact` doesn't exist, then there will be no values selected. I wan't to get `NULL` instead of nothing. It still need to `SELECT` the whole row! Can anyone help me?

ps. I think it's going wrong with the inner join (`ON o.idContact = c.id`);

Comment: Did you try using `LEFT` or `RIGHT` join depending on what you want?

Comment: left join on your first clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Replace your last `INNER JOIN` with `LEFT JOIN`.

Using `LEFT JOIN` you tell my main table (`offertes`) returns always result but if in secondary table (`contactperson`) there's no row matches returns NULL all fields of that table

```
SELECT k.name, c.name AS nameCustomer, o.*
FROM offertes o
INNER JOIN customers k
ON o.idCustomer= k.id
LEFT JOIN contactperson c
ON o.idContact = c.id;
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need an outer join instead.
e.g.

```
SELECT k.name, c.name AS nameCustomer, o.*
  FROM customers k LEFT OUTER JOIN 
       (offertes o INNER JOIN 
        contactperson c
        ON o.idContact = c.id)
       ON o.idCustomer= k.id;
```

(I assume there'll be a counterpart of an offerte in contactperson, else you'll need an outer join there as well)

Answer (score 0):

you need to rewrite a query using outer join

```
SELECT k.name, c.name AS nameCustomer, o.*
  FROM customers k
  LEFT OUTER JOIN offertes o ON o.idCustomer = k.id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN contactperson c ON o.idContact = c.id;
```